# Django form data from array

Tags: django, django-forms

If the name field is left blank, then the color is used to populate the name field for the Car.

My problem is the color field is a ManyToMany field so its returning the array- it returns something like this:

```
[<car_color:_red>] Car
```

I would like it to return the first value in the array, like this:

```
Red Car
```

#### models.py

```
class car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Colors)
```

#### forms.py

```
class AddCar(forms.Form):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AddCar, self).clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')
        new_name = '%s Car' % (cleaned_data.get('car_color'))
        if not name:
            self.cleaned_data['name'] = new_name
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Just for testing, use: `new_name= '%s Car' % (cleaned_data.get('car_color').name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using a loop to get the color.

```
if not name:
    for color in cleaned_data.get('marker_color'):
        self.cleaned_data['name'] = '%s Trail' % (color)
```